# image processing gamma color matrix

Tags: android, image-processing, image-editing, colormatrix

I am including a photo editor in my app and so far I have solved the brightness and contrast option . But i don t know hot to set the color matrix for  and what are the values .

here is for brightness /contrast

```
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });
```

This 2 work but I don t know what is the color matrix for gamma. 
can any one tell me gamma color matrix. 
i want to change bitmap gamma value using seekbar and also processing speed was good.

Comment: You can't ajust gamma with just the ColorMatrix because it's just an affine transformation of the RGBA color space. Gamma adjustment is a non linear transformation of the color space.

Comment: can you suggest me any good method with good processing speed to change a gamma of any bitmap image